# Ассиметричное шифрование - алгоритм

Tags: криптография, шифрование, rsa, aes

Решил для себя понять как работает RSA шифрование.

Вот алгоритм, который у меня заработал с первого раза. Я использую php и расширение openssl

> Данные зашифрованные публичным ключем, можно расшифровать только
>   приватным ключем.

1. Клиент генерирует 2 ключа публичный и приватный.
2. Публичный ключ клиент передает на сервер. Допустим POST запросом
3. Сервер генерирует случайный пароль. И сохраняет его гдето себе.
4. Так же сервер шифрует этот пароль открытым ключем, полученным от клиента.
5. Сервер отправляет зашифрованный пароль обратно на клиент.
6. Клиент расшифровывает полученный пароль, своим приватным ключем. Все!

Мы добились того что на клиенте и на сервере у нас есть "синхронизированный" одинаковый пароль, который далее можно использовать для симметричного шифрования.

Верный ли такой алгоритм?
Непонятно зачем нужно обмениваться публичными ключами? Ведь в литературе пишут именно об обмене публичными ключами. Разве не достаточно такого алгоритма.

Comment: Если предположить отсутствие https — откуда вы знаете, что вы (как клиент) отправили свой публичный ключ именно на настоящий сервер, а не на сервер злоумышленника, который перехватил ваш интернет и подделал сервер?

Comment: Это я понял. Эта проблема не решаема алгоритмами шифрования. Эта проблема решается сертификатом. Который подтверждает ху из ху. Но в целом этот алгоритм правильный?

Comment: Если есть сертификат, то в этом алгоритме просто нет никакого смысла, потому что безопасность обеспечит сертификат и всё связанное с ним

Comment: Да я для академических целей интересуюсь. Я не собираюсь его нигде применять.

Comment: Шифрование придумано для того, чтобы защищаться от реальных практических перехватчиков и злоумышленников, и рассматривать что-то академическое здесь бессмысленно.

Comment: Так вы по сути описали https только в другую сторону. В реальности вам сервер посылает свой публичный ключ с подписью УЦ. Вы проверяете подпись по своей базе, создаёте пароль, шифруете публичным ключом и отправляете на сервер. Он расшифровывает и вот у вас общий пароль которым симметрично шифруется весь дальнейший трафик

Comment: В SSH то же самое, только нет УЦ и при первом коннекте вам показывают некий идентификатор и спрашивают доверять или нет https://habr.com/ru/post/425637/

Answer (score 0):

В общем идею Вы поняли правильно. Только с ключами все наоборот. Public Key должен передавать не клиент серверу, а сервер клиенту:

1. Чтобы удостовериться, что публичный ключ получен действительно от этого сервера, клиент получает ключ от сервера не просто, в сертификате X.509 подписанном CA (Certification Authority).
2. Чтобы убедиться, что сертификат действительно подписан указанным CA клиент расшифровывает подпись с помощью имеющегося у него в браузере или OS публичного ключа CA.
3. На основе публичного ключа сервера клиент создает разделяемый (общий) ключ и сохраняет его у себя.
4. Клиент шифрует созданный разделяемый ключ и в зашифрованном виде передает серверу.
5. Сервер расшифровывает зашифрованный разделяемый ключ с помощью своего приватного ключа и таким образом получает разделяемый ключ у себя.
6. Handshake состоялось. Далее клиент и сервер имея разделяемый ключ могут обмениваться симметрично зашифрованными данными.

   ```
                 Client                                  Server
                      | Hello -------------------------> |
   Creates Common Key | <-- X.509 with server public key |
                      | Encrypted Common Key ----------> | Decrypts Common Key
           Common Key | <---- Symmetric Encryption ----> | Common Key
   ```